# Typescript protected methods should be permitted in interface descriptions? or am I just an idiot?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, microservices

I've scoured through posts seeking an explanation why typescript interfaces only permit public method signatures. The common explanation is that an interface should only describe the aspects relevant to the code consumer/developer. Whilst I can completely understand that argument for private scoped methods and attributes, what if the code consumer is intending to specialize the class further with a subclass? The protected class members are just as important in this use case as the public methods.... or am I completely idiotic and need my pronouns adjusted?

Comment: If you need to describe common features of a class that are hidden from the consumer then you should be using abstract classes.

Comment: Also, you don't often use interfaces to type class instances because classes provide their own type. `const a: MyClass = new MyClass() // valid`

Comment: Thanks you - makes perfect sense... :) Have a great weekend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elaborate on what @kelly, said in that first comment, you want [abstract classes.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#abstract-classes-and-members)

From the docs:

> The role of abstract classes is to serve as a base class for subclasses which do implement all the abstract members. When a class doesn’t have any abstract members, it is said to be concrete.

---

Let’s look at an example:

An `interface` or `type` describe a single value and how you are allowed to interact with it.

But a class is a bit more complicated. A class has an instance that it creates, and a constructor which makes instances (that has a wholly different type), and provides a way to do inheritance. This is a lot of functionality for just one interface.

And an `abstract class` is one that provides typings for subclasses and inheritance, but cannot be instantiated directly. And it may have abstract methods that will be required to be implemented by subclasses.

---

For instance:

```
abstract class A {
    abstract pub(): string
    protected abstract prot(): string
    protected realProt(): string {
        return 'real protected method'
    }
}
```

This class has a public method `pub()`, and a protected method `prot()`, both with no implementation. Any subclass of `A` must implement those methods to fulfill that contract.

```
class B extends A {
    pub() {
        return 'a public string'
    }

    prot() {
        return 'a protected string'
    }
}
```

This class implements the required methods from the abstract class. Visibility modifiers are not required because they are defined by class `A`.

```
class C extends B {
    callProt(): string {
        return this.prot() + this.realProt()
    }
}
```

This class extends `B` and can call protected methods of either of its ancestors.

---

And, of course, you can use each of these classes in a type position for instances of those classes.

```
const a: A = new C()
```

---

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgggg3gKAUIVEhngQAcBXEACgEoAuBUgSwDsBzAoiqAewgBTeEIAmxcNDiI+ghszZcehOcNESoQ4MgAKAiApbQOnXCqKEtEKlHYIA5Fp2UDI4RIC2QiAAt+Yg4WAL54oXgoaBgAQghCAB7C7GIY2PiW1HT05paW1rb2DsCUNMissMZQpkGW4RkGDDm5Vj4FjsVq7uKV1SFheBGo6AgAwnGJQskxTYSwOnoNTD1cM7n5dgh+rGAAdGqNANSbvts7zgvy9H3hsPzskMTM2AC8COxCAO6jDEA)

Comment: Thank you so much Alex! This is a wonderful explanation and beautifully put together :D Rockstar.

Comment: You're welcome! Welcome to stack overflow, and please don't forget to accept the answer to your question that helped you the most by pressing the checkmark to the left of that answer.

Comment: I'm so sorry this took so long to get back.. didn't notice my inbox!